# Bash replace string which contains single quotes with other string

Tags: bash, replace, sed

I am trying to replace a string with sed. Unfortunately the string contains single quotes and "::" symbols. Therefore I have some troubles using sed.

I need to change `configuration::set('feature', '0')` into `configuration::set('feature', '1')`. 
What I tried:

```
sed 's%configuration::set('feature', '0')%configuration::set('feature', '1')%g'  file.cf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use double quotes around the whole thing so that `'` doesn't end the command string and use a capture group to avoid repetition:

```
sed "s%\\(configuration::set('feature', '\\)0'%\\11'%g"  file.cf
```

Based on the comments (thanks), I've added the closing quote to the match and replacement to make it slightly more robust. I opted to go against my own advice here due to the number of characters being so low.

Comment: Won't work correctly if, for example, the file has `configuration::set('feature', '01')`

Answer (score 1):

It's only a quote problem. Enclose your sed command in double quotes (if there is nothing that bash may expand) or escape all single quotes inside.

```
sed 's/configuration::set('"'"'feature'"'"', '"'"'0'"'"')/configuration::set('"'"'feature'"'"', '"'"'1'"'"')/g'
```